Azure B2C - How to show a custom HTML page after password reset flow?
The default behavior is auto login after password reset but we have a requirement to redirect to a html page from where user can sign in.
I have created a content definition and a technical profile but I do not know how to make the orchestration steps in passwordreset journey to make it work.
I managed to stop the auto loggin after the password reset but unable to get the redirect to work.

To achieve an "HTML page from where user can sign in," you would need native auth, i.e., a B2C API that you can call.
B2C does not support native API.
Could you perhaps do another sign-in via the custom policy?

You should be creating a technical profile that collects email address and password through DisplayClaims. The technical profile must contain validation technical profile that validates if the email address and password is valid. You could add an orchestration step that runs this technilcal profile before 'SendClaims' orchestration step and after the password is reset.
Basically, you are recreating the same login experience. This technical profile looks similar to login but it is not the same as login. For example, 'Forgot Password' link or Signup link would not exist in this 'Login-replica' technical profile.
This is a work around I implemented for our product.

I was able to redirect the user to the custom HTML page. But now the customer wants that firstname should also be visible in the HTML body. Like "Hello $firstname , you password has been reset". I know that it is only a static page which has a sign in button also but passing the claim to this html page seems tricky.

You could use claim resolvers for that. While redirecting to the signin page, you can pass the user's firstname in query params. This way, you could use claims resolvers to read that name's value and update that using a displayclaim. You would need to use FormatStringClaim claims transformation to modify the $firstname into 'Hello $firstname'.
You could store 'Hello $firstname' to a claim (lets call it 'greeting'). The 'greeting' claim 'userinputtype' should be set to 'paragraph'. You then add a displayclaim in your singin technical profile to display the name.
